# MySQL: Not being able to compare string values as dates correctly

Tags: mysql, string, date

I am trying to display rows that fall between two ranges. Those two ranges will be dates. One of the column stores the date as a String in the format of "8-10-2017 / 05:00 AM"
In order to compare the values I am using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Game` WHERE (Home_School_Name = 'Paarl Boys' OR Away_School_Name = 'Paarl Boys') && Status = 'NOT STARTED' && STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(Start_Time,LOCATE(' ',Start_Time)),'%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '2017-8-10' AND '2017-15-10'
```

Now there are two games that should get returned in the result.  8-10-2017, 9-10-2017. When I send the range as 2017-1-10 and 2017-8-10, it displays the first game. When I try 2017-8-10 and 2017-8-12. It displays both the games. But It stops returning both of them when I go greater than 12. 
I know something is wrong with the date formats that I am passing. But I have not been able to figure it out. I have also seen similar questions but none of them worked for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use `DATE` or `DATETIME` as data type?

Comment: I was given to work on this structure. If I change it, some of the reports will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really be storing date/times as `datetime`, not as strings.  Using the wrong data type just makes subsequent work that much harder.

MySQL generally takes date constants in ISO standard format, YYYY-MM-DD, so try this:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM `Game` g
WHERE 'Paarl Boys' IN (Home_School_Name, Away_School_Name = 'Paarl Boys') AND
       g.Status = 'NOT STARTED' &
       STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(Start_Time, LOCATE(' ', Start_Time)), '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2017-10-08' AND '2017-10-15'
```

Comment: Thanks. You did point me in the right direction, however I had to change the format in STR_TO_DATE as %d-%m-%Y as well.